# Рандом в Html Сайте

Tags: html

Как вставить генератор рандомных чисел в HTML сайт, созданный через Блокнот
иначе говоря: есть ли какие-не будь теги для Рандома?

Comment: можно на JS написать функцию для создания рандомного числа и закинуть в html-документ

Comment: HTML - язык разметки. И только. Смотрите в сторону JS для каких-либо манипуляций.

Comment: Ну с кодом понятно а вывести то как его?

Answer (score 5):

На чистом HTML это невозможно. Однако, без особых проблем делается на JS

```
<script>
let num = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
//где min и max - минимальное и максимальное число необходимого диапазона
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = num;
//где id - это id элемента, в который нужно вставить получившееся число
</script>
```